# Connect to db4o using datanucleus JDO

Tags: java, eclipse, jdo, datanucleus, db4o

I've been reading the datanucleus tutorial and couldn't even understand how to connect to a db4o database.

Normally, without using datanucleus, I'd open the connection like this:

ObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile("myDb");

The question is simple: what should I do to do that simple thing using datanucleus JDO?

I'm using Eclipse with the datanucleus plugin installed and filled the Connection URL field just like the tutorial says, but I have no idea how to open/close/store in the database.

I also have imported the following .jar to my project:

datanucleus-db4o-3.0.0-release /
datanucleus-api-jdo-3.0.0-release

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Support for db4o was dropped after v3.0 of DataNucleus.

You connect to a db4o database using JDO how you would with **any** database with JDO; create a PMF with a set of PMF properties and, in the case of db4o, make sure you specify

```
datanucleus.ConnectionURL=db4o:file:{my_db4o_file}
```

which is defined well enough in [this page](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/db4o/support.html)